# CSS String Length

Tags: javascript, css

and thanks first of all for looking at my post.

My question today is about CSS. I have a script which connects to a database and creates an XML stream. Within this stream is a telephone number string which is formatted as 8005551212

This XML stream is exploded and parsed into my final page.

However on my final page I need to display this string as (800)555-1212

Does CSS have the capability to convert this string? I have been reading up on `word-wrap: break-word but I may be going down the wrong path....

Thanks Again,
--Matt

Comment: You can't in CSS. If you can't change the thing that is exploding XML you can postprocess in JavaScript

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use Javascript for this, not CSS.

Here's a very simple one-line JS regex function to do the job for you:

```
var formatted_phone = plain_phone.replace(/^(\d{3})(\d{3})(\d{4})$/,"($1)$2-$3");
```

(note, the line above assumes that the phone number is already known to be in the correct format; it doesn't do any validation)

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 4):

You can do it with javascript like this

```
var n = '8005551212';
var n1 = n.substring(0,3);
var n2 = n.substring(3,6);
var n3 = n.substring(6,11);

document.write("(" + n1 + ")" + n2 + "-" +n3);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/jasongennaro/N5Gsu/

Basically, your chopping the string into several pieces and then adding them together again with the new bits you want

If you need to do it for several numbers, you could use a function.

```
var n = ['8005551212','8005551213','8005551214'];

function formatNumbers(){
    for(var i=0; i<n.length; i++){
        var n1 = n[i].substring(0,3);
        var n2 = n[i].substring(3,6);
        var n3 = n[i].substring(6,11);
        document.write("(" + n1 + ")" + n2 + "-" + n3 + "<br />");
    }
}

formatNumbers(n);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/jasongennaro/N5Gsu/1/

To build on the comment from @Dennis, switched out `document.write` for `.innerHTML`

```
document.getElementById("a").innerHTML += 
  "(" + n1 + ")" + n2 + "-" + n3 + "<br />";
```

http://jsfiddle.net/jasongennaro/N5Gsu/2/

Comment: Good answer, but you probably want `document.getElementById("foo").innerHTML =` instead of `document.write`

Comment: @Dennis.  Thanks.  I was doing that for the fiddle, but your are correct.  Answer edited.

Comment: much easier to write a one line regex replace rather than manually chopping the string into bits. :-)

Answer (score 0):

CSS cannot achieve this, note the CSS should be used for **styling** and *not* for content managing and behaviour.

instead, use JavaScript to achieve this:
http://jsfiddle.net/Ke6Ns/

```
function formatPhone(phone) { 
  return "("+phone.substring(0,3)+")"+phone.substring(3,6)+"-"+phone.substring(6,11); 
}
```